# Text is briefly hidden behind video

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js to create full screen pages.
If you scroll to the next section(s) and scroll back to the first section (with video background and the overlay text), the text is briefly "hidden" behind the video before showing up again.
This problem only happens on my Chrome(Version 49.0.2623.112) so far.

HTML:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
      <div class="text">1233123123</div>
      <div class="video-background">
          <video autoplay muted loop>
            <source data-src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"/>
          </video>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
       <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide1">
       <img src="" data-src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/examples/imgs/iphone-blue.png" />
       </div>
        <div class="slide" data-anchor="slide2">Two 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
       <img src="" data-src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/master/examples/imgs/intro.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="section">Four</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section {
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.text {
  font-size: 123px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}
div.video-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}
div.video-background video {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'],
  sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
});
```

Demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqxqqj

Comment: I think it's a Chrome rendering issue. And I don't think there is anything you can do about it. I might be wrong too.

Comment: @mlegg It does not work. :(

Comment: @Roy there's a solution. I answered with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use translate3d(0,0,0) for the text:

```
.text {
  font-size: 123px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: So hardware acceleration makes it render so fast that you don't see the blink anymore?

Comment: No. That's not the reason. It s because of some issues with browser's rendering and translate3d. fullpage.js uses css3 transformations and that's why you need also to use them in the video to solve it. Why? Ask the browser's developers :)