# Remove transition effect from (fullPage.js)

Tags: fullpage.js

I have kind of a silly problem, but I can't find the solution so I have to ask for help. I currently use the plugin 'fullPage.js' and use a video background, you can find the site with some code here:

http://xn--rur-3man9d.is/fullPage.js-master/examples/backgroundVideo.html

When you scroll down and up again you will see that the text kind of 'fade in' and it's quite annoying. I have found out that if I open the file jquery.fullPage.js and change "css3: true," to false I solve the problem. However, that solution also delete a part of the transition effect. I have tried to change transition effects in the CSS file but nothing works.

HTML code:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/backgroundVideo.html

CSS-code:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.css

JS-code:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/jquery.fullPage.js

Anybody who knows how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this topic](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/183) on fullPage.js' issues tracker or [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658559/text-is-briefly-hidden-behind-video/36671466#36671466) in stackoverflow.

This is a bug with some browsers and translate3d animations.

Just use:

```
#section0 .layer{
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

I'll add the changes on the demo.